# What Datastore/Database runs on top of S3?

Tags: database, amazon-s3

What Datastore/Database runs on top of Amazon S3 or S3-compatible storage?

I understand that S3 is an Object Storage and thus not a database, but a database must have something to store data into, thus, my question is if there is a Database or Datastore that saves its data on an Amazon S3 or S3-compatible storage instead of a local file system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some databases and database-like products that use S3 (or *can* use S3).

- [Amazon Athena](https://aws.amazon.com/athena/)
- [S3 Select](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/s3-glacier-select/)
- [Apache HBase](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-hbase-s3.html)
- [Redshift](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-redshift-spectrum-exabyte-scale-in-place-queries-of-s3-data/)

Also, if you want some theory, here’s a MIT paper about [Building a Database on S3](https://people.csail.mit.edu/kraska/pub/sigmod08-s3.pdf).

This is by no means exhaustive, but it’s probably a good place to start.

**Update**

Here are some more that aren't AWS owned software.

- [Cassandra](https://dzone.com/articles/s3-compatible-storage-with-cassandra)
- [Hadoop](https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/AmazonS3)—this isn't a database, but S3 already provides you with key-value storage, and Hadoop can provide you with querying.
- [s3-db](https://www.npmjs.com/package/s3-db)

Ultimately, you need to consider what sort of query functionality you need and what sort of consistency you can tolerate.

Comment: So it means all "DB" based on S3 is part of AWS platform services? There's not open source DB that does the same?

Comment: HBase is an open source project. I don't know if the HBase to S3 connector is open source, but you don't pay extra for it and you can't run HBase on S3 without using S3 anyway. If there's something specific you're looking for, you should make your question more specific.

Comment: I mean, I am using Wasabi S3-compatible, accessed through key-pair is that possible with such DB?

Comment: Some traditional databases can use S3 as a storage engine, like MariaDB: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/using-the-s3-storage-engine/